# Using Windows Vista/7 themes with g++

Tags: winapi, g++

I have done an application with `g++` using pure winapi, but every control looks very old. How can I use the new nice themes 7 and Vista offer? Everything I have read so far says that I must include an XML file saying explicitly that I want those themes, but I don't think that is possible with `g++` . So, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following `#pragma comment` below your `#include` directives: `#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")` ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I am going to try that when I have a compiler at hand, but the `name.exe.manifest` solution worked for me. Didn't know `#pragma comment` worked in g++ too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to include a [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your project.
This is just a simple xml file that you add to your project as if it were a .cpp or .h file.
It will enable the nice visual styles, but you're not there yet!

The font is still the ms shell dlg which is not all that amazing.
To "extract" the standard font, you use the [GetStockObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the DEFAULT_GUI_FONT flag

```
HFONT font = (HFONT) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
```

To calculate the new dialog units for this font you can use this little snippet.

```
LONG units = GetDialogBaseUnits();
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
SIZE size;
TEXTMETRIC tm;  
HFONT font = (HFONT) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
SelectObject(dc,font);
GetTextMetrics(dc,&tm);
GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",52,&size);
float avgWidth = (size.cx/26+1)/2;
float avgHeight = (WORD)tm.tmHeight;
float dialogUnitWidth = 2*(avgWidth/LOWORD(units));
float dialogUnitHeight = 2*(avgHeight/HIWORD(units));
```

dialogUnitWidth and dialogUnitHeight now contain the dialog units in pixels.
See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125681) article for more information.

Comment: I was just about to ask about text font. thank you for the mind reading :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know g++. But if the result of this environment/language you get is a **simple EXE** and the controls that are used are **standard Windows controls** adding a manifest to the exe will do the job.

The easiest way is to create a valid manifest with the complete Name of the exe and add .manifest to the Name. (i.e. foo.exe.manifest)